# Microphone time delay estimation

Tags: microphone, sound

I'm trying to estimate the direction of arrival of sound using a microphone array. This requires me to find the delay of the sound signal upon arriving the different microphones. For  convenience, I was hoping to use 4 USB mini microphones and connect them all to a USB hub to create a 4 mic array. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  The main problem is that the audio sample clocks between the four microphones will not be phase-aligned and possibly not match in frequency.  Because of this you won't know how to align the four data streams to do proper processing.

It would be better to get a single 4-channel audio USB interface.  At least then you'll know that they are all time aligned and sync'd.  You can find many of these types of devices at Sweetwater Sound and Guitar Center.

Comment: Is there a cheaper alternative to this? Ultimately the whole thing is supposed to work as an embedded system. I just want to test the algorithm now.

Comment: For a short period of time, you could use independent USB interfaces and calibrate out any delay variation by exposing them to a source from which they are all equidistant, but the calibration may go invalid in as little as a minute due to clock drift.  If you assume the delay is only on the digital side, it should be uniform with frequency and you could expose them to a reference source at a different frequency even during your experiment to maintain/verify calibration.  You could also consider electrically injecting the calibration source through a small capacitor.

Comment: I found a cheap mixer : http://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/MIX02-1A-4-Channel-Mini-Mixer-by-Gear4music/K84. It says its got 4 input channels. Can I use 4 mics and connect them to the mixer to have them synced? And more importantly, can I extract the required time delay information from this? (after digitizing the output)

Comment: @lonesword a mixer won't help.  It will just mix together the audio from all the mics, and you won't be able to identify the sound from the individual mics.  I expect you will have to process the individual audio signals directly, and simultaneously, to be able to extract the required timing information.

Comment: How you solve this issue in an embedded system is different and more specialized question that requires more info, eg what kind of control do you have over the hardware.

Comment: I got the mixer idea from here : http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/construction-tips/172153-diy-usb-microphone-array.html. Will finding a laptop with 4 usb ports and connecting one mic to each port help? David kessner said a USB interface would solve the issue. Is there a difference between a mixer and a usb interface?

Comment: A mixer combines the channels, a multi-channel USB interface would keep them separate (though you may spend a long time fighting with drivers to get the data in a useful form).  Frankly it sounds like you are in a bit over your head here - perhaps you should try some initial experiments with only two microphones using a common stereo setup, and gain some practical experience with that.

Comment: Using 2 microphones is good enough. I'm hoping to use mini mics since I'm not looking for very high sensitivity. But again, would i need a usb interface to do this?

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Calibrating using a audio source and a known distance to the mics is do-able, but much more difficult than you'd expect.  And as you point out, clock drift becomes an issue in a very short time.

Comment: @lonesword - not if the computer you want to use has a stereo microphone input.  If it only has a mono one, you would need a USB interface with a stereo input.  Also if you only have line inputs, you will need an amplifier.